# How to ask excel to do sequenced formulas in single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here have some information in cell A1.

Then cell B1 has a formula (called "Formula1") to modify A1, resulting in B1 value.

Then cell C1 has a formula (called "Formula2") to modify B1 whose value was created after applying its formula to A1, resulting in C1 value.

Is there a way that I can write a formula which asks him in a single cell to do first formula 1 then formula 2 without needing to write 2 different formulas in different cells?

I tried writing in the formula box like this but it is comparing one to another instead of doing one then the other with the result of the first one:

=Formula1

=Formula2

Also tried =Formula1&Formula2 and =Formula1+Formula2, but they do other things...

How could I write formulas in a single cell saying:

=Formula1 THEN Formula2 THEN Formula3, etc. (each higher formula being done to the result of the former one)

Thanks

---

### Example

Input Cells

A1:Michael.John$Josh.Andrews

A2:Michael%Josh.Andrews

A3:Michael John

A4:Michael.John

Formula1 for column B: =LEFT(A1,FIND("$",A1& "$")-1)

Formula2 for column C: =IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"$","")))=1,LEFT(B1,FIND("$",B1)-1),IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"%","")))=1,MID(B1,FIND("%",B1)+1,LEN(B1)-FIND("%",B1)),IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","")))>=1,B1,"")))

I am having to write column A, Then do formula1 for getting column B, Then again do formula2 on top of column B value after its formula 1 result, for just then to get column C. This is making the excel chart display information that I dont want it to appear nor calculate by parts, but show only final result calculated at once.

I would like to have only columns A and B in which A is the input, and B has all the formulas calculated at once. How do I do one single formula with those 2 formulas to be done first formula1 and then formula2 applied to formula1 result directly?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your original question, "*Is there a way that I can write a formula which asks him in a single cell to do first formula 1 then formula 2 without needing to write 2 different formulas in different cells?*" - NO, it doesn't exist until the latest releases of Excel 2016.

There are many effective ways of writing formulas is excel, and based upon the examples you have provided, I believe the below should serve your needs

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("%",A1)+1,1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("$",A1& "$")-1))-IFERROR(FIND("%",A1),0)))),"",MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("%",A1)+1,1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("$",A1& "$")-1))-IFERROR(FIND("%",A1),0)))
```

Since you have not actually stated your requirements, I can only assume that you are trying to achieve the below:

1. Truncate any text **after** $ symbol, if present, AND THEN
2. Truncate any text **before** % symbol, if present, AND THEN
3. Check for the presence of a "." symbol, if not present blank out else accept the output of the previous step

Have a go and let us know your thoughts.

Comment: I also noticed a trivial but important detail in your original formula, you are checking for exactly '1' occurrence of the "%" symbol before dropping off any text before that "%" symbol, If not, then you move on to checking the presence of a ".". There may be a flaw in this approach compared to what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Hello Bharat,

What I need to do is as follows in this order:

* If $ exists, get whats behind the first $ that appear on cell only (excluding $), only if it has points inside the text (not after, not before the text).
* If didnt get result yet, then check for the appearance of the first % in the cell, if it exists, get result whats after it (excluding %) only if it has points inside (not after nor before the text).
* If $ nor % exist, then copy the cell as result only if it has point inside (not before nor after text). If there is no point, result is blank.

Thanks

Comment: You need to elaborate your requirements more clearly, with all ifs and else-ifs covered before we continue to work further on this, or state what is not met in the solution that I have provided. At present you seem to be drip-feeding and developing your requirements which is proving to be counter-productive for many of us

Comment: Hello Bharat, thanks for your help. If you could check following details please, would be perfect, as follows: 

1) After all the formula did, if still appears in the result a $ then to that result, delete the $ and whats after it to the right. 

Example:

Cell: MichaelMichael%John.John$This is a test for a long sentence
Result now is: John.John$This is a test  (its overpassing the $)
Result should be: John.John (after it gets this final result of this % searching, delete whatever comes after a $ including it)

Comment: 2) Also, the formula is cutting some part of the text when $ and % happen:

Example:

Cell: MichaelMichael$John.John%This is .a test for a long sentence
Result now is: This is .a tes  (result would be correct if it didnt stop in half of the sentence, not printing all characters)
Result should be: This is .a test for a long sentence  (in here its grabbing correct information but cutting it for some reason)

Rest is all perfect.

Thanks

Comment: @Joao, for your first example in the comments where % occurs before the $ in the input text, you can fix this easily by using the updated formula below, I think this should also fix any issues in your 2nd example. If it works, please mark my answer as accepted: =IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("%",A1)+1,1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("$",A1& "$")-1))-IFERROR(FIND("%",A1),0)))),"",MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("%",A1)+1,1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("$",A1& "$")-1))-IFERROR(FIND("%",A1),0)))

Comment: In your second example, the output should be blank, because once you drop everything after the $ symbol, you are left with "MichaelMichael". Since this doesn't have any "." in it, a blank output will be returned

Comment: Hello Bharat, have copied formula here and is giving error, is it working there?

Comment: Absolutely, I tested it before posting the message. What part is not working for you, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Result is this: #NOME? saying formula has something wrong.

Comment: My excel is in portuguese, after translating the function names and changing comma for ; then is like this: =SE(ÉERROS(PROCURAR(".";EXT.TEXTO(A1;SEERRO(PROCURAR("%";A1)+1;1);NÚM.CARACT(ESQUERDA(A1;PROCURAR("$";A1& "$")-1))-SEERRO(PROCURAR("%";A1);0))));"";EXT.TEXTO(A1;SEERRO(PROCURAR("‌​%";A1)+1;1);NÚM.CARACT(ESQUERDA‌​(A1;PROCURAR("$";A1& "$")-1))-SEERRO(PROCURAR("%";A1);0)))

Comment: Spanish, hmmm, this is turning out to be more interesting than what I thought earlier. You can upload image in the body of your question with a suitable heading, say, **Additional information**. Language might be a problem and I might not be of much help, still let's give it a try.

Comment: ps: have already marked the accepted for your hapiness with a number 1. as per language is portuguese not spanish. so far what you said before i translated and was ok, this one, its giving error yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71902/discussion-between-bharat-anand-and-joao).

Comment: The last version of formula by chat is now perfect. Thank you

Comment: The formula in your answer contains the subexpression `LEN(LEFT(` *`x`* `,` *`y`* `))` twice.  Can’t that always be reduced to just *```y```*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll build a complex formula, using substitution of the prior formula's as inputs.  Assuming something like:

`A1` =2 (your input)
`B1` =A1*2 (your first operation)
`C1` =B1/12 (your second operation)

A single formula might be `C1` `=(A1*2)/12`, using () to force an order of operation.

Comment: Hello Dav, in your example, it works fine because your formulas are made up only with numbers not with functions. But if inside B1 the formula is IF, FIND, SUBSTITUTE, LEN, MID, LEFT, RIGHT, SUMPRODUCT, etc. multiple things and then C1 needs to do some lots of things to B1 result, then how to merge all so it makes one and the other and instead of having cells A1, B1, C1, only have A1 with input and B1 whith the whole stuff to calculate and then calculate on top of the results of first calculation? In other words, how do you write C1 =(A1*2)/12 using B1 cell in this formula instead of (A1*2)?

Comment: @Joao it would be easier to answer if you gave a real life example of the input and what you expect as the output, as well as the actual formula you have tried.

Comment: Hello Scott, have added example above in original text. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you’ve accepted an answer
that doesn’t answer the question you asked, I’ll offer another one.

To rephrase your question,
you have two functions, which you call "Formula1" and "Formula2";
I’ll call them *`f()`* and *`g()`*. 
You are currently defining `B1=f(A1)`
and `C1=g(B1)`,
and you want to define `B1=g(f(A1))`,
eliminating the middle man.

It would be nice if you explained *why* you want to do this. 
After all, this is such a common technique
that we often recommend it in answers here. 
If a problem requires a particularly complicated expression,
we frequently advise the asker to create a “helper column”
to hold an intermediate result. 
The final, desired result is then generated using the helper column as input.

But, if you just don’t want to see the `B1`
(i.e., `f(A1)`) value on your spreadsheet,

- The simple fix is to hide Column `B`.
- The more complicated fix is to
  move the `f(A1)` formula from `B1` to `Z1`
  (or some other out-of-the-way column),
  and then set `B1=g(Z1)`. 
  If you want, you can hide Column `Z`.
- An even more advanced approach is to implement *`g()`*
  as a VBA user-defined function. 
  Then you can define `B1` as

  ```
  =g(LEFT(A1,FIND("$",A1&"$")-1))
  ```

  using your Formula1 in worksheet formula form.
- Or you could take this to its logical conclusion:
  implement *`f()`* and *`g()`* as VBA user-defined functions,
  and define `B1` as

  ```
  =g(f(A1))
  ```

  You can, of course, give the functions names that reflect what they do.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the ability to obtain the formula has existed in Excel for 30 years.

The Excel 4 macro function `GET` was able to do so, as one of the MANY things it could do, and one used it like one does the better known, nowadays, `EVALUATE` function.

It's pointless to expand further on that, since `FORMULATEXT()` now exists.

But for the record, it could be done and easily, for a very, very long time. Perhaps why MS was so very, very long in producing a function like `FORMULATEXT()`? And similarly, perhaps why MS is so, apparently, resistant to the very obvious need for a simple cell-side formula to convert a text string directly into a formula. Yes, `EVALUATE` works fine-ish, (emphasis on "-ish"), but it isn't cell-side, and it is difficult, usually, to use inside a formula, due to the indirect way of using it. So no formula snippet tables for instance from which one builds a formula from text snippets and a lookup based upon factors in the data at hand. Therefore, no simple formulas in cells with easy to maintain snippets. (Also, no, `INDIRECT()` is utterly not something useful for what I describe.)

But Bharat Anand was incorrect in stating it oculd not be done back then. `GET` function, option 6.

Comment: It appears that you  misunderstand the question.